# Merging Pandas DataFrame within a specific Date Range

Tags: python, pandas

I've 2 DataFrames. One for `Invoice Data` and the other for `Promotion Dates`.

`Invoice Data` DataFrame

```
+------------+-------------+---------------+
| LocationNo | InvoiceDate | InvoiceAmount |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
|      A     |  01-Jul-20  |       79      |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
|      B     |  01-Jul-20  |       72      |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
|      C     |  01-Jul-20  |       24      |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
|      A     |  02-Jul-20  |       68      |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
|      B     |  02-Jul-20  |       6       |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
|      C     |  02-Jul-20  |       27      |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
|      A     |  03-Jul-20  |       25      |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
|      B     |  03-Jul-20  |       62      |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
|      C     |  03-Jul-20  |       58      |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
|      D     |  03-Jul-20  |       36      |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
|      E     |  03-Jul-20  |       65      |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
|      F     |  03-Jul-20  |       81      |
+------------+-------------+---------------+

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'LocationNo':['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','D','E','F'],
    'InvoiceDate':['01-Jul-20','01-Jul-20','01-Jul-20','02-Jul-20','02-Jul-20','02-Jul-20',
                  '03-Jul-20','03-Jul-20','03-Jul-20','03-Jul-20','03-Jul-20','03-Jul-20'],
    'InvoiceAmount':[79,72,24,68,6,27,25,62,58,36,65,81]
})
```

`Promotion Dates` DataFrame

```
+------------+----------------+--------------+
| LocationNo | PromotionStart | PromotionEnd |
+------------+----------------+--------------+
|      A     |    01-Jul-20   |   02-Jul-20  |
+------------+----------------+--------------+
|      B     |    02-Jul-20   |   03-Jul-20  |
+------------+----------------+--------------+
|      C     |    03-Jul-20   |   05-Jul-20  |
+------------+----------------+--------------+
|      D     |    01-Jul-20   |   05-Jul-20  |
+------------+----------------+--------------+
|      E     |    02-Jul-20   |   02-Jul-20  |
+------------+----------------+--------------+
|      F     |    05-Jul-20   |   06-Jul-20  |
+------------+----------------+--------------+

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'LocationNo' : ['A','B','C','D','E','F'],
    'PromotionStart':['01-Jul-20','02-Jul-20','03-Jul-20','01-Jul-20','02-Jul-20','05-Jul-20'],
    'PromotionEnd':['02-Jul-20','03-Jul-20','05-Jul-20','05-Jul-20','02-Jul-20','06-Jul-20',]
})
```

My Task is to Merge both the DataFrames based on 2 conditions & add value `Yes` to a new column `Promotion`
if these conditions are met.

conditions are as follows

1. `LocationNo` should match
2. The `InvoiceDate` should be between the respective `LocationNo`'s `PromotionStart` and `PromotionEnd`.

Basically, to merge only If the `InvoiceDate` falls between `PromotionStart` and `PromotionEnd` dates.

My desired output is as below

```
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| LocationNo | InvoiceDate | InvoiceAmount | Promotion |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      A     |  01-Jul-20  |       79      |    Yes    |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      B     |  01-Jul-20  |       72      |           |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      C     |  01-Jul-20  |       24      |           |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      A     |  02-Jul-20  |       68      |    Yes    |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      B     |  02-Jul-20  |       6       |    Yes    |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      C     |  02-Jul-20  |       27      |           |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      A     |  03-Jul-20  |       25      |           |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      B     |  03-Jul-20  |       62      |    Yes    |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      C     |  03-Jul-20  |       58      |    Yes    |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      D     |  03-Jul-20  |       36      |    Yes    |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      E     |  03-Jul-20  |       65      |           |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      F     |  03-Jul-20  |       81      |           |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
```

I know how to merge columns based on multiple conditions. But, in this case, I need to merge within  `Date Range`.

kindly, let me know how should i approach to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try `merge` and filter:

```
out = df_1.merge(df_2, on='LocationNo', how='left')

df_1['Promotion'] = np.where(out['InvoiceDate'].between(out['PromotionStart'], out['PromotionEnd']),
                             'Yes', '')
```

Output:

```
   LocationNo InvoiceDate  InvoiceAmount Promotion
0           A   01-Jul-20             79       Yes
1           B   01-Jul-20             72          
2           C   01-Jul-20             24          
3           A   02-Jul-20             68       Yes
4           B   02-Jul-20              6       Yes
5           C   02-Jul-20             27          
6           A   03-Jul-20             25          
7           B   03-Jul-20             62       Yes
8           C   03-Jul-20             58       Yes
9           D   03-Jul-20             36       Yes
10          E   03-Jul-20             65          
11          F   03-Jul-20             81
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it won't be practical for large datasets since the merge might create thousands of df_1 duplications