# pyjanitor conditional joins between date range based on columns

Tags: pandas, pyjanitor

**data**:
[Merging Pandas DataFrame within a specific Date Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63890031/merging-pandas-dataframe-within-a-specific-date-range)

I want to use pyjanitor referring this [post](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join) but it doesn't give if merge with another columns at the same time.

**Try**

```
df_1.conditional_join(
...     df_2,
...     ("InvoiceDate ", "PromotionStart ", ">="),
...     ("InvoiceDate ", "PromotionEnd ", "<=")
... )
```

**output**

```
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| LocationNo | InvoiceDate | InvoiceAmount | Promotion |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      A     |  01-Jul-20  |       79      |    Yes    |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      B     |  01-Jul-20  |       72      |           |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      C     |  01-Jul-20  |       24      |           |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      A     |  02-Jul-20  |       68      |    Yes    |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      B     |  02-Jul-20  |       6       |    Yes    |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      C     |  02-Jul-20  |       27      |           |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      A     |  03-Jul-20  |       25      |           |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      B     |  03-Jul-20  |       62      |    Yes    |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      C     |  03-Jul-20  |       58      |    Yes    |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      D     |  03-Jul-20  |       36      |    Yes    |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      E     |  03-Jul-20  |       65      |           |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      F     |  03-Jul-20  |       81      |           |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
```

Comment: What output are you trying to get?

Comment: @HenryEcker I update.

Comment: I _think_ you're looking for something like `df_1.conditional_join(df_2, ('LocationNo', 'LocationNo', '=='), ('InvoiceDate', 'PromotionStart', '>='), ('InvoiceDate', 'PromotionEnd', '<='), how='left')` but I'm not sure why you'd use a `conditional_join` here instead of a standard merge followed by where (as in [the answer](/a/63890093/15497888) on the linked post).

Answer (score 1):

With [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join) you need to include another tuple for the equi join:

```py
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df_1['InvoiceDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['InvoiceDate'])
df_2['PromotionStart'] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['PromotionStart'])
df_2['PromotionEnd'] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['PromotionEnd'])

(df_1
.conditional_join(
    df_2, 
    ('LocationNo', 'LocationNo', '=='), 
    ('InvoiceDate', 'PromotionStart', '>='), 
    ('InvoiceDate', 'PromotionEnd', '<='))
)
        left                                right
  LocationNo InvoiceDate InvoiceAmount LocationNo PromotionStart PromotionEnd
0          A  2020-07-01            79          A     2020-07-01   2020-07-02
1          A  2020-07-02            68          A     2020-07-01   2020-07-02
2          B  2020-07-02             6          B     2020-07-02   2020-07-03
3          B  2020-07-03            62          B     2020-07-02   2020-07-03
4          C  2020-07-03            58          C     2020-07-03   2020-07-05
5          D  2020-07-03            36          D     2020-07-01   2020-07-05
```

As @HenryEcker rightly pointed out, your question can be solved by merging, then filtering. For your use case [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join) might be overkill; for equi joins, what [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join) does is to intercept the indices that are generated from pandas [internal merge function](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/6b93a0c6687ad1362ec58715b1751912783be411/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py#L608) (a hash implementation), and then run the non-equi joins, before creating the final dataframe. No sorting is done, unlike the strictly non equi joins, as hash merge are usually faster for equi joins (caveat - R's [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) uses some form of binary search for its joins and is quite fast, usually even faster than Pandas). For large dataframes, it might come in handy with some performance gains; your mileage might vary.

Let's look at a silly example below with a million rows - the code below is based on the [dev version](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git):

```py
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git

np.random.seed(3)
df = pd.DataFrame({'start':np.random.randint(100_000, size=1_000_000),
                   'end':np.random.randint(100_000, size=1_000_000)})
dd = pd.DataFrame({'ID':np.random.randint(100_000, size=1_500_000)})

df.head()
   start    end
0  71530  85703
1  67224  37802
2  77049    652
3  59011  99059
4  48056  26108

dd.head()
      ID
0  25816
1  92958
2  62607
3  89684
4  13434


%timeit df.merge(dd, left_on='start', right_on = 'ID').loc[lambda df: df.end >= df.ID]
1.27 s ± 17.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df.conditional_join(dd, ('start', 'ID', '=='), ('end', 'ID', '>='))
597 ms ± 16.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


# verify both dataframes are the same
cond_join = df.conditional_join(dd, ('start', 'ID', '=='), ('end', 'ID', '>='))

pd_merge = df.merge(dd, left_on='start', right_on = 'ID').loc[lambda df: df.end >= df.ID]

pd_merge.reset_index(drop=True).equals(cond_join)
True


# memory consumption
In [167]: %load_ext memory_profiler

In [168]: %memit df.conditional_join(dd, ('start', 'ID', '=='), ('end', 'ID', '>='))
peak memory: 1599.06 MiB, increment: 173.16 MiB

In [169]: %memit df.merge(dd, left_on='start', right_on = 'ID').loc[lambda df: df.end >= df.ID]
peak memory: 2207.29 MiB, increment: 624.08 MiB
```